# implements onChildClickListener

Tags: android, android-listview, android-view

I'm working with a custom expandablelistview, and the adapter is outside my activity. In my activity i'm able to set the onclicklistener fine with

```
    mTopicsExpandListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            Log.i("MEAT", "This child row was clicked!");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But to avoid the need to use static variables, in the near future, i wanted to be able to use implements OnChildClickListener in the adapter itself

```
public class MExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter implements OnChildClickListener {
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    Log.i("MEAT", "This child row was clicked!");
    return false;
}
```

but the latter does nothing. Is there something different the second case? IsChildSelectable is set to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need to wire your new class in:

In your activity you need:

```
mTopicsExpandListView.setOnChildClickListener(new MExpandableListAdapter());
```

Have you done that?